# How to show datalabels in chartkick vue

Tags: vuejs2, chartkick

Hellow, i want to show the percentage of a piece of a pie chart, i dont know how to enable it or how to use the plugin i'm using chartjs-plugin-datalabels

any help will be appreciated, before posting this question i've already tried to solved on my own, Tanks!
[actual code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJONV.png)

this is my actual code all that's commented already tried

Comment: Can we please see some code to help you? We are flying in the dark here

Comment: If you already solve it. please separate your question with your answer, accept your own answer, and post the code like `this line`.

Comment: i couldn't fix it i had to install apex charts, which solved my problem